# CI/CD updating nuget packages during build process

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, nuget, gitlab-ci

I am using a local GitLab CI/CD runner to create and upload nuget packages when a new commit is sent to staging with the following code.

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
script:
    - "dotnet restore \"CICD Test\\CICD Test.sln\" --no-cache"
    - "dotnet pack \"CICD Test\\CICD Test.sln\" -c Release"
    - dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg --source $SOURCE_URL --api-key $API_KEY --skip-duplicate
only:
    - Staging
```

This is working correctly, however, i am wondering if the following is possible to do.

In the c# solution i have 3 projects App1, App2 and App3. App3 references the nuget package of App2, App 1 references App2. In this hypothetical scenario is there a way when building the nuget packages to build App 3, update the nuget package on the server then use this updated package to Build App 2, then do the same to build App 1 all in the same CI/CD pipeline? For clarity i included an image below of the project outline and references.

[image: Project outline]

in case it is needed using c# .netcore3.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to use `ProjectReference` for your references between `App1`, `App2` and `App3`.

When you pack they'll be automatically converted to `PackageReference` at the latest version